# How to properly kill a Go process from Node

Tags: node.js, go, gruntjs

I want to build a Grunt task that spawns a Go server and then kills and respawns it when the Go source files change.

I am spawning the Go process like this:

```
goProcess = child_process.exec('go run main.go', ...
```

Later I'm trying to kill the process like this:

```
if (goProcess) {
    goProcess.kill('SIGINT');
}
```

But the Go process doesn't die.

How can I properly kill the Go process within Node?

I have a working example here https://github.com/sporto/go-must-die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`child_process.exec` runs the command in a shell and seems to be returning the PID of the shell process. Use spawn instead.

`go run` creates an executable and runs it with a different PID. Try building a binary with `go build main.go` and running the binary from node.js.

```
goProcess = child_process.spawn('./main')
```

Comment: Thanks, as you said the go code has to be built first before trying to spawn it using Node. It works that way.